# Converting from ANSI to UTF-8 using script

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix, utf-8

I have created a script (.sh file) to convert a CSV file from ANSI encoding to UTF-8.
The command I used is:

```
iconv -f "windows-1252" -t "UTF-8" $csvname -o $newcsvname
```

I got this from another Stack Overflow post.
but the `iconv` command doesn't seem to be working.
Snapshot of input file contents in Notepad++

Snapshot of firstcsv file below
[image]

Snapshot of second csv file below,

[image]

EDIT: I tried reducing the problematic input CSV file contents to a few lines (similar to the first file), and now it gets converted fine. Is there something wrong with the file contents itself then? How do I check that?

Comment: Which input file are you meaning? and what is not working? the script as such or the `iconv`?

Comment: @Inian I can't seem to figure it out. Because I tried this script on another file, and that converted fine. I'm not sure but could there be something wrong with the input file ($csvname)?

Comment: Could you please tell us what kind (format) of file you are talking about?  If your second find is some kind of binary format, it can't work.  Otherwise, we would need enough information to reproduce the problem in order to help you.

Comment: @Fred Both file is a .csv file. I also edited my OP to include a screenshot of the second file

Comment: @Inian Can you please mention what other info is needed? I will try to provide them. I'm using Putty to run this script which will convert the input file's encoding from ANSI to UTF-8. The input filename is stored in $csvname

Comment: @Inian Yes Inian, that's what I mentioned. It stores the file name.

Comment: ANSI is not an encoding!

Comment: @Inian I'm sorry for sounding so amateurish but where exactly do I put those commands? something like this?

iconv ....... --verbose
echo $

Comment: @SoumyadeepPaul: do a `iconv --verbose -f "windows-1252" -t "UTF-8" $csvname -o $newcsvname`

Comment: @Inian I tried that and the command executes but there is no difference in the output. Also, the file stays the same encoding i.e. ANSI. I used the echo $ at the end and it just echoes the $ symbol on the screen.

Comment: @SoumyadeepPaul: I meant `echo $?`

Comment: @Inian I didn't get your last question. Sorry. Anyway, I removed the echo part and it still executes the same, with no difference in the output file.

Comment: @Inian ok, please tell me what other info should I provide? I apologize again for not framing my question right

Comment: I don't see any error in your example, and your posting is confusing. What exactly are you expecting to? What is the input of your command, what is the output you get, and what is the output you expect?

Comment: @user1934428 My input and output files are both CSV files. The script should convert the input file's encoding, which is ANSI to UTF-8 encoding.
At present, the script converts the first example file (screenshot) just fine. But it fails to convert for the second file(screenshot). The second file's encoding stays the same (ANSI).

Comment: In the screenshot of your second file, I don't see a single character which would look odd. Can you give me an example of a character in the second file, which should have different representation under UTF-8, but doesn't?

Comment: @user1934428 Both the file contents remain (look/ appear) the same whether it's in ANSI or UTF. Im checking the encoding from Notepad++. Is there any way I can check if there's something wrong with the contents of the second file?

Comment: Did you consider the possibility, that the file contains only characters, which have the same representation in Windows-1252 and UTF-8? That's why I asked you to post a screenshot, where I can really recognize, that the conversion did not work correctly.

Comment: @user1934428 The file contents are huge and not possible to check individual characters. If iconv did actually work, wouldn't the file encoding show as UTF 8 in Notepad++? I really appreciate your suggestions. Actually, the file would be fed into another program, which accepts ONLY UTF 8, and throws an error on this file.

Comment: No. Imagine a file, which consists only of the single letter 'e'. How should Notepad++ (or anyone else) "decide" that this is a ASCII-e, an ANSI-e or a UTF-8 e? They have the same binary representation and hence are identical. If you want to enforce that it looks like UTF-8, you could create a BOM at the beginning of the file, and Notepad++ would then for sure decide then that it's UTF-8. The question is then: Will the other applications you are going to use with this file, understand the BOM? This depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @user1934428 wow, very explained answer. Thanks. I'll try to echo the BOM part into a file, and then concatenate the actual file contents after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python chardet Character Encoding Detector to ensure existing character encoding format.

iconv -f {character encoding} -t utf-8 {FileName} > {Output FileName}

This should work. Also check if any junk characters are exist in file or not, that may create error in conversion.